# Ordering by specific value in Activerecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rails-activerecord

In Ruby on Rails, I'm trying to order the matches of a player by whether the current user is the winner.

The sort order would be:

- Sort by whether the current user is the winner
- Then sort by created_at, etc.

I can't figure out how to do the equivalent of :

```
Match.all.order('winner_id == ?', @current_user.id)
```

I know this line is not syntactically correct but hopefully it expresses that the order must be:

1)  The matches where the current user is the winner
2) the other matches

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use a CASE expression in an SQL ORDER BY clause. However, AR doesn't believe in using placeholders in an ORDER BY so you have to do nasty things like this:

```
by_owner = Match.send(:sanitize_sql_array, [ 'case when winner_id = %d then 0 else 1 end', @current_user.id ])
Match.order(by_owner).order(:created_at)
```

That should work the same in any SQL database (assuming that your `@current_user.id` is an integer of course).

You can make it less unpleasant by using a class method as a scope:

```
class Match < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.this_person_first(id)
    by_owner = sanitize_sql_array([ 'case when winner_id = %d then 0 else 1 end', id])
    order(by_owner)
  end
end

# and later...
Match.this_person_first(@current_user.id).order(:created_at)
```

to hide the nastiness.

Comment: This did the trick exactly. I did it nastily in the controller but will try and figure out an elegant way to integrate scoping in the model (by passing the current user?) or in a helper method.

Answer (score 3):

This can be achived using `Arel` without writing any raw SQL!

```
matches = Match.arel_table
Match
  .order(matches[:winner_id].eq(@current_user.id).desc)
  .order(created_at: :desc)
```

Works for me with Postgres 12 / Rails 6.0.3 without any security warning
[image: demo]

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do sorting on the ruby side of things (instead of the SQL side), then you can use the Array#sort_by method:

```
query.sort_by(|a| a.winner_id == @current_user.id)
```

If you're dealing with bigger queries, then you should probably stick to the SQL side of things.

Comment: On this one I get the following error: {comparison of FalseClass with true failed}. In addition don't forget you need brackets not parentheses for the block!

Comment: It may need to be coerced to a numeric using I suppose, something that admits the <=> operator.

Comment: To be honest I didnt' investigate the error much because in the long run (if the application ever scales, ha!) the solution isn't optimal - I'm quite sure there is a solution to the error, of course. Thank you for following up!

Answer (score -1):

I would build a query and then execute it after it's built (mostly because you may not have `@current_user`.  So, something like this:

```
query = Match.scoped

query = query.order("winner_id == ?", @current_user.id) if @current_user.present?

query = query.order("created_at")

@results = query.all
```

Comment: You know, this is exactly what I had tried before posting (don't worry about the @current_user since the site authenticates in a before_filter) and I get this error: PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  syntax error at or near ","
LINE 1: ...nfirmed, play_date DESC, created_at DESC, winner_id == ?, 34
                                                                   ^
: SELECT "matches".* FROM "matches"  ORDER BY confirmed, play_date DESC, created_at DESC, winner_id == ?, 34